# YouTube Data API Quota Usage - 10 thousand units per day, but 300 thousand per 100 seconds per user?

Tags: youtube-data-api

"Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota allocation of 10 thousand units per day."

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota
[image]

And the following are the default max number we can set up.

Does this make sense?

- Queries per day - 10,000
- Queries per 100 seconds per user 300,000
- Queries per 100 seconds 3,000,000

Total project's quota whole day is 10,000. But per 100 seconds, per user quota is 300,000? and per 100 seconds quota is 3,000,000?

Comment: We had 50M queries per day in 2018 and that was awesome. A while ago, google decreased almost all the api keys to 10K units per day.